# Automator sequential renaming for one file at a time

Tags: applescript, automator

I have found many tutorials on how to rename some files using a "batch-renaming" type of workflow, but I have a different issue.

I'm moving files one at a time into a folder, not all at once, so the Make Sequential block in Automator doesn't see it as "A1, A2, etc", but rather "another A1, so make it A1-1". In other words, it doesn't see the existing files inside the folder and therefore every time it restarts from the base number I set it to.

Apparently I should/might use an Applescript to check existing files, but I have never got into it, let alone write one. Is there a way besides the Applescript or is it the best/only solution?

Comment: It would be helpful to get more detail on what exactly your end goal is, and what your script currently does.

Comment: @robmathers My end goal is to have Automator check the folder what is the highest number in the filenames, as in "A5" for example and then use this info to rename the file I have just added to "A6" and not "A5-1" as if it was a duplicate file.So far I only have the renaming part.